# Jenkins failed to start in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins

go to run jenkins after doing an upgrade, and get the following:

```
start jenkins
start: Job failed to start
```

That's it...nothing shows up in jenkin's log...so it is difficult to debug to say the least.
(and it isn't running already, or anything like that).

Is there another log somewhere that I should be looking at that would be helpful?
(I am assuming answer to this problem will be somewhat iterative, so hopefully someone can start me on a path to debug this)

Comment: Which logs are you looking at? How was Jenkins installed?

Comment: apt-get was the install method.

I looked at /var/log/jenkins/*.log (there are many there, but one is the most recent one, and the others are older archives).

Comment: Additional information:
After more of my own digging, the only logs I could see changing were /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log

In both of these there is one line which reads:
"init: jenkins pre-start process (####) terminated with status 127"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So, knowing it was a pre-start error allowed me to investigate more deeply.

Further digging allowed me to figure out that the exact line in the `/etc/init/jenkins.conf` file was one pointing to the `/usr/share/jenkins/bin/maintain-plugins.sh`

Looking at this location, I found it was not present (ie. no bin directory).  This means that `jenkins-common` was no longer installed for some reason...odd indeed...going into `apt-get` and doing an install of this component again led to the error:

```
dpkg error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins-common_1.409.1-0ubuntu4.2_all.deb ...
```

having seen this error before and refreshing my memory via google gave the following solution:

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins-common_1.409.1-0ubuntu4.2_all.deb
```

This allowed the installation of common to proceed as normal.  After this, all I had to do was replace the `/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war` with my backed up copy (because ubuntu is far behind the latest release version), and I was able to start the server again.

I am not exactly sure what caused the problem to begin with, but it was likely during an apt-get upgrade/clean process...and because of the weirdness with jenkins conflicting with jenkins-common, it did not repopulate the `/usr/share/jenkins` directory properly.

regardless, am glad it is working again. :)

Comment: This was super helpful for me. I didn't have the same problem, but I was able to diagnose more about what was going on by logging the output of the startup log

"sudo cat /var/log/upstart/jenkins.log"

Comment: I am glad it was useful. :)

Comment: I had this problem too and figured out what caused it.  I first installed jenkins from the ubuntu repositories, saw that most plugins weren't supported then uninstalled it.  Then I installed it from jenkins' repsotories, but I forgot to add --purge to the uninstall of the previous jenkins package.  The scripts and configs were left behind causing this issue.

Comment: Just adding a comment, if it is helpful to anyone else having the problem. I initially installed jenkins on Ubuntu by following the jenkins instructions to add 'deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary' to /etc/apt/sources.list.  When I had to reboot the server, jenkins would not start.  cat /var/log/upstart/jenkins.log showed maintain-plugins.sh: not found.  I had to remove the jenkins entry in /etc/apt/sources.list before doing a apt-get update, apt-get upgrade jenkins because once it's installed it will add a source in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list

Answer (score 6):

Instead, you can run the following before the install to properly clean up any conffiles left by the   distro version:

```
sudo apt-get purge jenkins
```

Then install the correct version.

Comment: Handy, but...
*If you've got a running system and don't necessarily want to risk blowing things away (that you need or have configured)...then this might not be the best approach.

Comment: This may be true in general, but in this case I found that doing so didn't destroy any Jenkins config, because it doesn't store this config in /etc .

Comment: This solved my issue. Tried install the distro supplied version, realized it was out of date for a plugin I wanted to use. Running the purge command resolved the errors I was getting. Thank you very much.

Comment: On Ubuntu the configs/jobs/workspaces are stored in /var/lib/jenkins and **will be deleted** on re-install. Make a backup first.

Comment: On Debian 8.7. Make a back up first. It deleted all the old configuration.

Comment: @CasualT What is the best solution on running system. I tried everything today after Updating Debian 7.8 to 8.7. As a last resort I used purge and lost all data and even changed port as well. Now I restored to last instance.

Comment: Did you try the answer I had above with the more specific dpkg command(s)? disclaimer: it is quite situation-dependent how you solve this issue after updating jenkins.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS use Java 9 as default java

Jenkins 2.107.2 still use Java 8

[Solution]

Install Java 8 before install Jenkins

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/"
sudo apt install jenkins
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49937744/900684

Answer (score 5):

I went to see the jenkins logs
`tail -f /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`

In my case it didn't start because I used incompatible java version.
Update and make sure it sees correct java (In my case it should have been opened using JRE 1.7. To check, please use  `java -version` command) and all should work

Comment: This answer is getting outdated, but the approach in any case should be:
1. Go see the logs for some useful information.

2. Make sure you are using compatible and updated Java runtime env.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me:

```
sudo rm /etc/init/jenkins.conf
sudo update-rc.d jenkins defaults
sudo service jenkins start
```

Then....

```
root@core:/# service jenkins start
* Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server jenkins                    [ OK ]
```

Borrowed from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jenkinsci-users/eW_yEWLojFc/tFhb8DKoRHUJ

Answer (score 1):

I got from this link: https://serverfault.com/questions/710680/jenkins-not-starting-in-ubuntu

It might be caused by a full disk.
To be really sure, try running it manually. Like this:
`/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1`