# Jenkins not starting on KDE Neon

Tags: java, jenkins, ubuntu-16.04

Installed KDE Neon Dev Stable Edition (Based on Ubuntu 16.04LTS), installed openjdk 8 and the Jenkins 2.83 (LTS). Installation went ok until the installer attempted to start jenkins (systemctl start jenkins)

At that time i got this error

```
Feb 08 10:29:23 UX31A jenkins[13911]:    ...fail! 
Feb 08 10:29:23 UX31A systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=7 
Feb 08 10:29:23 UX31A systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time. 
-- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has failed 
-- Defined-By: systemd 
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel 
--  
-- Unit jenkins.service has failed. 
--  
-- The result is failed. 
Feb 08 10:29:23 UX31A systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Unit entered failed state. 
Feb 08 10:29:23 UX31A systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. 
Feb 08 10:29:23 UX31A sudo[13908]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Tried to see if it can find java, it does, also tried to add in config, the path to java so that there will be no conflicts, but the error persists.

Anyone had this issue?

Thanks!

EDIT
systemctl status jenkins.service

```
iosifbancioiu@UX31A:~$ systemctl status jenkins.service
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-02-09 18:13:02 EET; 1min 4s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Feb 09 18:13:01 UX31A systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Feb 09 18:13:01 UX31A jenkins[11420]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Feb 09 18:13:01 UX31A su[11438]: Successful su for jenkins by root
Feb 09 18:13:01 UX31A su[11438]: + ??? root:jenkins
Feb 09 18:13:01 UX31A su[11438]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Feb 09 18:13:02 UX31A jenkins[11420]:    ...fail!
Feb 09 18:13:02 UX31A systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=7
Feb 09 18:13:02 UX31A systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
Feb 09 18:13:02 UX31A systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 09 18:13:02 UX31A systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

journalctl -u jenkins output

```
journalctl -u jenkins
-- Logs begin at Thu 2018-02-08 21:20:06 EET, end at Fri 2018-02-09 18:15:21 EET. --
Feb 09 18:13:01 UX31A systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Feb 09 18:13:01 UX31A jenkins[11420]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Feb 09 18:13:01 UX31A su[11438]: Successful su for jenkins by root
Feb 09 18:13:01 UX31A su[11438]: + ??? root:jenkins
Feb 09 18:13:01 UX31A su[11438]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Feb 09 18:13:02 UX31A jenkins[11420]:    ...fail!
Feb 09 18:13:02 UX31A systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=7
Feb 09 18:13:02 UX31A systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
Feb 09 18:13:02 UX31A systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 09 18:13:02 UX31A systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: can you please post these logs also `systemctl status jenkins.service` and `journalctl -u jenkins`?

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy Added in the question

Comment: How did you install Jenkins?

Comment: I do think, It is unable to build the session. So it must be Permissions problem. So how did you install it in the first place???

Comment: @SV Madhava, installed from repo, following the steps from jenkins.io, installed and tried to start as root

Comment: Then it can be because so many reasons. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133964/jenkins-failed-to-start-in-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133964/jenkins-failed-to-start-in-linux) follow this it might be helpful to you.

Comment: if you can't figure it out, `tail -f /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` please add this log to the question also.

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy The log is empty, tails does not show any update in that file

Comment: /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1 with this one works, but it reinstall jenkins all the time, not sure what the issue is... any idea?

Comment: Its because i think you are killing the process and starting the `jenkins` via command line again i think. Instead [please do like this](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216118748-How-to-Start-Stop-or-Restart-your-Instance-).