# Install Jenkins in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS failed (Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.)

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

### [Symptoms]

- Install Jenkins by using official steps, but failed with error message **Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time**.
- Reproduce Steps

  ```
  wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
  sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/"
  sudo apt install jenkins
  ```
- Console log

  ```
  gaspar@jenkins:~$ sudo apt install jenkins
  ...
  Setting up default-jre-headless (2:1.9-62ubuntu2) ...
  Setting up jenkins (2.107.2) ...
  Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
  See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
  invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.
  ● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-04-19 10:03:05 UTC; 9ms ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 27282 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=7)
  Apr 19 10:03:03 evt-jenkins systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
  Apr 19 10:03:03 evt-jenkins jenkins[27282]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
  Apr 19 10:03:03 evt-jenkins su[27313]: Successful su for jenkins by root
  Apr 19 10:03:03 evt-jenkins su[27313]: + ??? root:jenkins
  Apr 19 10:03:03 evt-jenkins su[27313]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
  Apr 19 10:03:03 evt-jenkins su[27313]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user jenkins
  Apr 19 10:03:05 evt-jenkins jenkins[27282]:    ...fail!
  Apr 19 10:03:05 evt-jenkins systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=7
  Apr 19 10:03:05 evt-jenkins systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
  Apr 19 10:03:05 evt-jenkins systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
  dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure):
   installed jenkins package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
  ...
  ```

### [Environment]

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Beta2
- Jenkins 2.107.2

Answer (score 62, accepted):

### [Root cause]

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS use Java 9 as default java
- Jenkins 2.107.2 still use Java 8

### [Solution]

- Install Java 8 before install Jenkins

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
  sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
  wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
  sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/"
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt install jenkins
  ```

Comment: Thanks for this. I used openjdk-8-jre instead and it worked

Comment: After adding apt-get repo don't forget to update `sudo apt-get update` otherwise it's not found

Answer (score 43):

1. Install java 8

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

2. Set default java version as java 8

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

3. Add the key

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

4. Add repository

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/"
```

5. Install jenkins

```
sudo apt install jenkins
```

Comment: `oracle-java8-installer` didn't work for me and I had higher version of java in my system, by `sudo update-alternatives --config java` I managed which version to use.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre` what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it also give an error due to some permission changed. You can try this:

```
chown root:root /tmp

chmod ugo+rwXt /tmp
```

Answer (score -1):

FWIW, my problem exhibiting the same symptom and solution was that the disk was full.