# Jenkins failing after session close on start

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, systemd, jenkins-cli

I've been fighting with jenkins for a bit now, finally got it happy with it's java versioning and path, but now when I start the service I get the following output:

```
Oct 22 16:39:11 server systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Oct 22 16:39:11 server jenkins[8758]: Correct java version found
Oct 22 16:39:11 server jenkins[8758]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Oct 22 16:39:11 server su[8795]: (to jenkins) root on none
Oct 22 16:39:11 server su[8795]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Oct 22 16:39:11 server su[8795]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user jenkins
Oct 22 16:39:12 server jenkins[8758]:    ...fail!
Oct 22 16:39:12 server systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=7/NOTRUNNING
Oct 22 16:39:12 server systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 22 16:39:12 server systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
```

From what I can see this is still failing, however there are no logs located in /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log, it is just empty.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and have Jenkins configured to use JDK 11

Comment: Have you seen [Install Jenkins in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS failed (Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49937743/1744774) already?

Comment: @GeroldBroser unfortunately yes, already running it with java 8, also tried it with 11

Comment: Have you checkd `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`?